# Symfony form collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to add a formType in a other form type.

CustomerType:

```
class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstname', 'text', array(
                    'required' => 'required'
                ))
                ->add('middlename')
                ->add('lastname')
                ->add('email', 'email')
                ->add('groups', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'MV\CMSBundle\Entity\Group',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('g')
                                  ->orderBy('g.name', 'ASC');
                    }
                ))
                ->add('profile', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new ProfileType()
                ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MV\CMSBundle\Entity\User',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'customer';
    }
}
```

ProfileType:

```
class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('isActive', 'checkbox', array(
                    'required' => false
                ))
                ->add('phone')
                ->add('address')
                ->add('city')
                ->add('zipcode')
                ->add('country')
                ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MV\NameBundle\Entity\Profile',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'profile';
    }
}
```

Then I get this message:

```
Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)", "MV\NameBundle\Entity\Profile" given.
```

If I comment that line i get: (just to check what will goes wrong ;) )

```
The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class MV\NameBundle\Entity\Profile. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "MV\NameBundle\Entity\Profile" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class MV\NameBundle\Entity\Profile to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.
```

What do I do wrong?

Symfony2: 2.1.8-DEV

Comment: Show us MV\CMSBundle\Entity\User class. It seems that MV\CMSBundle\Entity\User::getProfile returns object not collection...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not clear what your mapping is between your `Customer` entity and your `Profile` entity, but I guess there are 2 options:

---

**Option 1:** You have a OneToOne relationship (One customer can only have One profile). Therefore, you don't need the collection at all but simply need to [embed a single object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-single-object).

```
->add('profile', new ProfileType());
```

---

**Option 2:** You want a ManyToOne relationship (One customer can have many profiles). In that case, you need to use to [embed a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedding-a-collection-of-forms). If this is what you want, rename `$profile` to `$profiles` in your Customer entity, and do the following:

```
   //MV\CMSBundle\Entity\Customer  
   use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
   /**
   * Your mapping here. 
   * 
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MV\NameBundle\Entity\Profile")
   */
   protected $profiles;

    public function __construct()
    {
         //This is why you had an error, this is missing from your entity
         //An object was sent instead of a collection.
         $this->profiles = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Finally, update your database.

Comment: You are awesome.  I was trying to use form collections when all I needed was a simple embed of a single object.

Comment: I found this ages ago and realised I'd already upvoted it. I re-found it and wish I could upvote again. Here is a virtual kiss instead. x

Comment: I had to come back to a similar problem i had with mapping relationships and saw this post yet again as it helped me fix two different issues this past 6 months.  Thank you... Again!